# What is best way to pass multiple query parameters to a restful api?

Tags: php, api, rest

I am designing RESTful Api's and would like some advice on designing an API where the caller wants to query records based on more than one search parameter.

I have only seen restful apis that use one parameter.

how should i do this?

e.g. if i have created a restful api for a list of contacts, how would I format a call that returned all contacts with firstname==bob & surname==smith?

I guess it should be a GET because I am retrieving?

My only thoughts are:

http://api.myapi.com/contacts/firstname/bob&surname=smith

But that doesn't seem right ;-(

Please advice.

Also, do any of the php frameworks support this? e.g. symfony, konstrukt etc.

Comment: Yes, with symfony you can create URLs that look like `/contacts/bob/smith` easily.

Comment: would this force me into only allowing second param to be surname?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think

```
http://api.myapi.com/contacts?firstname=bob&surname=smith
```

is the way to go if you have a set of parameters, all of which are optional.

Comment: I agree; it is called the "query" string

Comment: yes, i like this. I guess by Query string u mean:  $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] contains firstname=bob&surname=smith. or: $_GET['firstname'] is better - less parsing needed. http://ditio.net/2008/06/12/php-query-string/

Comment: you could even loop through $_GET to build the query