# How do I use Request.RequestUri.Query in .NET? (Error 11 'System.Web.HttpRequestBase' does not contain a definition for 'RequestUri')

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-mvc-2, get

I'm rewriting a simple API GET function. I want to make it more flexible, so I tried to copy the example given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12597208/2188245).

My code:

```
  public IEnumerable<Distributeur> GetDistributeurs()
{
    NameValueCollection nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.RequestUri.Query);
    var departementCode = nvc["departementCode"];
    // BL comes here



    var repository = new LeadRepository();
    return repository.getDistributeurs(departementCode);
}
```

Unfortunately I get an error 'cannot resolve RequestUri' and on build:

> Error 11  'System.Web.HttpRequestBase' does not contain a definition for 'RequestUri' and no extension method 'RequestUri' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpRequestBase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I went to the microsoft [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.requesturi.aspx) but they are almost empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Request` object is an instance of `HttpRequest` - not `HttpWebRequest`. There is no property `HttpRequest.RequestUri`. The property you are looking for is `Request.Url.Query`:

```
HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You're confusing [`System.Net.HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) with [`System.Web.HttpRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx).

The former is used to initiate HTTP requests to foreign servers.  The latter is used to represent an HTTP request sent to your server (and is aliased as `Request` in pages and controllers, referencing `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request`).

Answer (score 1):

I am quite late...But I would like to share my experience to others. 
I had the same problem. Finally, I found it was because I inherited wrong base class.

```
API => System.Web.Http.ApiController
MVC => System.Web.Mvc.Controller
```