# ASP.Net Web API - custom url query binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'd like my Web API to support custom url querying on fields I don't know in advanced (they are user specified)

in an ideal world I'd like this url (fields not known in advance):

```
http://mysite.com/api/Query?SomeField=2&SomeOtherField=value
```

to bind with something like this action:

```
public string Query(Dictionary<string,string>? queryStrings) {
    // escape query fields and values
    // run query
    return result;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I pass multiple parameters to an ASP.Net Web API GET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937524/how-should-i-pass-multiple-parameters-to-an-asp-net-web-api-get)

Comment: Use `Request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString()` method inside `Query` action.

Comment: In the real world, you can't do that.

Comment: @GreyCloud because it's just not how the [Web API binding](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) works. You can, however, write your own binder to do it for you.

Comment: hence the title of the question regarding binding. @Vladimir Frolov that link doesn't deal with bindings

Comment: @James, turns out you can (!)

Comment: @GreyCloud no...you can't. You asked for the ability to bind your querystring to a `Dictionary<string, string>` parameter - you can't do this (at least without some sort of custom binder). I never said you couldn't of course just parse the querystring internally (i.e. your answer & Vladimir's comment).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Vladimir I've just got this controller:

[image]

to return this result:

[image]

which is what I was hoping for :)

{this is in Web API V5 RC}