# MVC Web API Routing to Wrong Action

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a web API controller, when I call the default Get action this works, when I call another specific action (GetReservationsForCustomer) this also works, but one action gives an error (GetReservationsByDate), it seems to route to the default Get action. Here is the code:

```cs
    // GET: api/Reservations
    public IQueryable<Reservation> GetReservations()
    {
        return db.Reservations;
    }

    [ResponseType(typeof(ReservationDTO))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetReservationsForCustomer(int CustomerId)
    {
        IEnumerable<Reservation> reservations = db.Reservations.Where(r => r.CustomerId == CustomerId).ToList();
        List<ReservationDTO> reservationList = new List<ReservationDTO>();

        foreach(Reservation reservation in reservations)
        {
            reservationList.Add(new ReservationDTO
            {
                id = reservation.id,
                ReservationStart = reservation.ReservationStart,
                Covers = reservation.Covers
            });
        }

        return Ok(reservationList);
    }

    [ResponseType(typeof(ListReservationDTO))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetReservationsByDate(DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate)
    {
        IEnumerable<Reservation> reservations = new List<Reservation>();

        if (EndDate != null)
        {
            reservations = db.Reservations.Where(r => r.ReservationStart.Date >= StartDate.Date && r.ReservationStart.Date >= EndDate.Date).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            reservations = db.Reservations.Where(r => r.ReservationStart.Date == StartDate.Date).ToList();
        }

        List<ReservationDTO> reservationList = new List<ReservationDTO>();
        foreach (Reservation res in reservations)
        {
            reservationList.Add(new ReservationDTO
            {
                id = res.id,
                ReservationStart = res.ReservationStart,
                Covers = res.Covers,
                CustomerEmail = res.Customer.EmailAddress,
                CustomerName = res.Customer.Name,
                CustomerPhone = res.Customer.PhoneNumber
            });
        }

        return Ok(reservationList);
    }
```

Here is my API call:

http://localhost:55601/api/Reservations/GetReservationsByDate/?StartDate=2018-03-04:T12:30:00

And here is the response:

```cs
{
    "Message": "The request is invalid.",
    "MessageDetail": "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult GetReservation(Int32)' in 'GreenLionBookings.API.ReservationsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."
}
```

Please note the specifics of the action are not relevant at this stage, I've butchered it a fair bit trying to get this to work! I've tried specifying a start date and end date and neither seems to work. It always seems to get routed to the default Get action.

Here is my RouteConfig:

```cs
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And here is my WebApiConfig:

```cs
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

So both basically just default.

Why is this not routing to the correct action, just for this one and not the others? I have another controller (Customers) which seems to work correctly for all actions too. I've read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection) and [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/2073471.aspx?Passing%20Multiple%20parameters%20in%20MVC%20with%20proper%20routing), and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937524/how-should-i-pass-multiple-parameters-to-an-asp-net-web-api-get) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246481/routing-with-multiple-parameters-using-asp-net-mvc) which I actually thought was pretty relevant and quite helpful, but didn't solve my problem.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `endDate` is a required parameter with no default. Therefore, that action is not a candidate for matching the route and the default route is chosen. That subsequently fails because there is no value for `id`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I've tried it with enddate too and it makes no difference. I've also tried it removing enddate completely from the action.

Comment: You should leave out the action name of the url and let the framework match the request against the parameters name, try it like this http://localhost:55601/api/Reservations?StartDate=2018-03-04:T12:30:00

Comment: @MarcusHöglund that seems to have done the trick. I'm getting a different error now but at least its routing to the correct controller: {
    "Message": "The request is invalid.",
    "MessageDetail": "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'StartDate' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult GetReservationsByDate(System.DateTime, System.DateTime)' in 'GreenLionBookings.API.ReservationsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."
}

Comment: But not sure why it says the parameter is null?

Comment: looks like you have a typeo in the date, 2018-03-04:T12:30:00 should be 2018-03-04T12:30:00

Comment: Also, as Aluan pointed out, you need to set the EndDate to nullable DateTime, use DateTime?, its a value type and not a reference type

Comment: @MarcusHöglund thanks for the typo catch. Also changing DateTime to nullable requires changing the code to use [...].Value.[...]. And also .Date can't be used in LINQ queries. It's working now, thanks. Although there's a logic error somewhere, it just returns all records at the moment.

Comment: @MattG Np, should I post this as an answer then?

Comment: @MarcusHöglund yes please and I will mark as accepted. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have a typeo in the date.

This `2018-03-04:T12:30:00` should be `2018-03-04T12:30:00`.

Then, to solve the routing problem, you could leave out the action name of the url and let the framework match the request against the parameters name.

Try it like this

```
api/Reservations?StartDate=2018-03-04T12:30:00&EndDate=2018-03-05T12:30:00
```

Then, if you want to be able to send nullable values to EndDate which is a value type of DateTime; make the DateTime nullable

```
[ResponseType(typeof(ListReservationDTO))]
public IHttpActionResult GetReservationsByDate(DateTime StartDate, DateTime? EndDate)
```

Notice the `DateTime?` which is a shorthand for `Nullable<DateTime>`