# Web api method not being hit when passing two parameters

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have written asp.net web.api method that accepts two parameters. It doesnt hit the web method when I call the method from postman. It works fine when I define the method to accept one parameter and call with one parameter but doesnt call when i define it with two parameters and call with two parameters

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/terms/{id}/{invested}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Details(int id, bool invested)
    {

        var viewModel = GetTermsViewModel(id, invested);
        if (viewModel == null) return NotFound();
        return Ok(viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I pass multiple parameters to an ASP.Net Web API GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937524/how-should-i-pass-multiple-parameters-to-an-asp-net-web-api-get)

Comment: What is the URL you are using with two parameters?

Comment: http://localhost:56888/api/terms/details/5508/true

Comment: Is it a problem if the parameter is boolean

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to specify `/details/` in your incoming request URL.
The URL you should be calling is

```
/api/terms/5508/true
```

Edit from comment:

To enable attribute routing, go to the `Register` method in your `WebApiConfig` class and add this:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Read about [attribute routing here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).

Comment: I get the message MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Terms' that matches the name '5508'.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier the the method hits if i just set the parameter to id and call it with id value. localhost:56888/api/terms/details/5508

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to use attribute routing, but maybe haven't enabled it and traditional convention routing is kicking in.

Comment: Could be. Not sure how to fix this