# Blazor: How to pass multiple parameter's from NavigateTo to a WEB API controller to download a file

Tags: blazor-server-side, webapi

I'm trying to use `NavivgateTo` in Blazor to pass a file id and name to download a file from my Download controller.

What is the proper setup? I've tried a number of possibilities and I keep seeing an error: Sorry, there is nothing at this address.

Razor Page

```
        public async Task SelectedDisplayDbItemChanged(DisplayDbItemsComboBoxItemDTO item)
        {
            Data = null;
            
            Data = GetDataTable();

            var fileId = await utilities.ExportDataTableToFile((DataTable)Data).ConfigureAwait(false);
            //navigationManager.NavigateTo($"api/download/fileId/" + fileId + "/fileName/" + "myfile", true);
            //?data1=678&data2=c-sharpcorner
            navigationManager.NavigateTo($"api/Download/{fileId}/{"myfile"}", true);
        }
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost("Download/{fileId}/{fileName}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string fileId, string fileName)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var fullPath = Path.Combine(DownloadPath, fileId);
                await using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    await stream.CopyToAsync(ms);
                }
                ms.Position = 0;
                return File(ms, "application/octet-stream", $"{fileName}.xlsx");
            }
        }
```

I've seen a lot of examples from the Razor page to the Razor page, but not from `NavigateTo` to a controller with passing multiple parameters.

[image]

I've tried these responses as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71130256/9594249
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71130256/9594249

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not like Asp.net MVC or razor page, in Blazor parameters are passed by [Parameter] tag

```
@page "/Download/{fileId}/{fileName}"
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? fileId { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string? fileName { get; set; }
}
```

please refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0

---

(Updated)

add to Program.cs or Startup.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options => {
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/DownloadPage", "Download/{fileId?}/{fileName?}");
    }
});
```

Pages/DownloadPage.cshtml

```
@page "{fileId?}/{fileName?}"
@model BlazorApp.Pages.DownloadModel
```

Pages/DownloadPage.cshtml.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace BlazorApp.Pages;

    public class DownloadModel : PageModel
    {
         private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
    
         public DownloadModel(IWebHostEnvironment env)
         {
             _env = env;
         }
        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            // work with RouteData.Values["fileId"] and RouteData.Values["fileName"]
        }
    }
```

please refer :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/243420/blazor-server-app-downlaod-files-from-server.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: This is calling a web api controller from within Blazor. Maybe I'm doing it all wrong (new to Blazor), but I need to open up another tab to download a file. My controller to download the file works good if I add in a static file id, file name.

Comment: Ah, now I see the point now. Blazor has no controller like ASP.net MVC so it will be complicated to do so and I think you have to work with startup.cs or program.cs. I'll update my answer.